# Reading the output file of scipSolver with Gurobi

Tags: scip

I want to read in a problem I was solving in SICP, with Gurobi. 
I can see that the java/jni library has functions for this:

```
public native void writeOrigProblem(long var1, String var3, String var4, boolean var5) throws NativeScipException;

public native void writeTransProblem(long var1, String var3, String var4, boolean var5) throws NativeScipException;
```

However I couldn't find more details on this output format. Is it compatible with [any of the formats here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/model_file_formats.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [list of the available file readers](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/group__FILEREADERS.php) (and the supported formats).

And there's also a documentation about the write functions [`SCIPwriteOrigProb()`](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/scip_8h.php#a2f6d67a1ccef7a6363e6d6a56523c0d0) and [`SCIPwritetransProb()`](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/scip_8h.php#ada41a57fc5a464ad565763d24e588d3a); you need to prepend the JNI function name with `SCIP` to find the corresponding C function in our doxygen documentation.